Friction for joints in Gazebo
I am trying to simulate a revolute joint in Gazebo Fortress (with ROS2 humble). I am importing the robot model using a urdf file and I use a ROS2 launch file to launch Gazebo sim. How can I apply any friction to the joint? I have tried two methods so far, both of which did not work:
Method 1:
Using a friction tag within the collision tag like below
<surface>
  <friction>
    <ode>
      <mu>10</mu>
      <mu2>10</mu2>
    </ode>
  </friction>
</surface>

Method 2:
Using friction and damping in the axis tag like below:
<axis>
  <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
    <dynamics>
      <damping>0</damping>
      <friction>1</friction>
    </dynamics>
    <limit>
      <lower>-1e+16</lower>
      <upper>1e+16</upper>
    </limit>
</axis>

Am I missing something? Is there any other way to this?

After a lot of trial and error, this is what ended up working:
<joint
    name="joint2"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0.025 0"
      rpy="0 1.5708 0" />
    <parent
      link="link1" />
    <child
      link="link2" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1">
    </axis>
    <dynamics damping="0.0"
              friction="0.01"/>
</joint>


For Gazebo, I specify friction for joints as this, and it works:
<gazebo reference="caster_wheel_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
    <mu1 value="0.1" />
    <mu2 value="0.1" />
</gazebo>

Normally, physical coefficients are defined under collision tag, you can also check this documentation: ROS

I tried using the gazebo reference tag but that did not work either. I have seen this work for some people but I haven't been able to make it work. I am wondering if it is because of the Gazebo version I am using.
